# z-index not working as expected for me

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I have a background image in my footer and I want the text to be on top of it. I tried using `z-index` but it is not working. Can somebody help me?

```
<footer class="page-footer blue" ng-controller="formCtrl">
    <img style="position:absolute;z-index: 3;height: auto; width: 100%; object-fit: contain;padding: 2%;" class="responsive-img" src="images/WorkWithUs_Desktop_Shapes.png">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="blue white-text">
            <div class="about-blue">         
                <div style="z-index: 4" class="row baa">
                    <div class="form-header mikado">WANT TO WORK WITH US?</div><br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col s12 l5 xl5">
                                <p style="font-size: 1.1em;">We're always looking to expand our team, with teachers and learners alike.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>                
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Why not use an **actual** background image?

Comment: Try using the image as footer background image ``style="background:url('path_to_picture')"``

Comment: @Shanid I tried doing that just like said. For some weird reason, it serves as background image outside the container only.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use `z-index` here. Just apply `position:relative` to the `.container` class and remove all `z-index` values

```html
<footer class="page-footer blue" ng-controller="formCtrl">
  <img style="position:absolute;height: auto; width: 100%; object-fit: contain;" class="responsive-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  <div class="container" style="position:relative;">
    <div class="blue white-text">
      <div class="about-blue">
        <div class="row baa">
          <div class="form-header mikado">WANT TO WORK WITH US?</div><br>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12 l5 xl5">
              <p style="font-size: 1.1em;">We're always looking to expand our team, with teachers and learners alike.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making these changes to your code.

```
<img style="position:absolute;z-index: 0;height: auto; width: 100%; object-fit: contain;padding: 2%;" class="responsive-img" src="images/WorkWithUs_Desktop_Shapes.png">
```

and also, add this css rule.

```
.page-footer .container {
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` has no effect for `position:static` (the default).

and in your code here i see you have this line without position

```
<div style="z-index: 4" class="row baa">
```

so you should define **position:relative/absolute;** to be able to have `z-index` work as expected

so if you do that everything will be ok

```
<div style="position:relative; z-index: 4" class="row baa">
```